# Getting Digits From the Beginning of a number C#

Tags: c#

I want to get digits of a long number one by one, sequentially starting from the beginning of the number. I want to do that by using while, for or if. Any idea?

Comment: Why not foreach?  The three options you mentioned for doing this seem odd.  Why not just use the best method available?

Comment: "Beginning" meaning most or least significant digit?

Answer (score 5):

```
int i = 123456;
foreach (char c in i.ToString())
{
    Console.Write(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have a number n

```
 int n = 12345;
```

to get the digits

```
int n = 12345;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i*=10)
{
    int d = (n % (i*10))/i;
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```